# Построение эллипсоида на Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Нужно построить эллипсоид (2*x - 1)**2 + (y + 3)**2 + (z - 2)**2 = 11. Но моя реализация корректно не отрисовывает вторую половину эллипсоида, т.к. не учитываются все варианты извлечения корня.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)
y = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zgrid = (11 - (2*xgrid-1)**2 - (ygrid+3)**2)**0.5 + 2
ax.plot_wireframe(xgrid, ygrid, zgrid)
plt.show()
```

Подскажите пожалуйста путь реализации моей задачи.

Comment: т.к. эллипсоид - симметричная фигура, то можно просто взять zgrid с противоположным знаком и сдвинуть

Comment: Типа так: zgrid2 = -((11 - (2*xgrid-1)**2 - (ygrid+3)**2)**0.5) + 2
ax.plot_wireframe(xgrid, ygrid, zgrid2)

Comment: @Виктор тогда не будет той половины, которая в ответе рисуется :)

Comment: @splash58 Но ведь значение кв. корня +/- , а +2 за корнем

Comment: @Виктор ну вот обе ветви и надо брать

Comment: @splash58 так я вроде это и сделал, нет? добавил отрицательные значения и их нарисовал

Comment: да, похоже. прозевал

Comment: @Виктор Спасибо, но при таком решении так же возникает проблема. Есть небольшая область область около полоскости z = 2 где нет решений для z. Непонимаю как с ней разобраться
`zgrid = (11 - (2*xgrid-1)**2 - (ygrid+3)**2)**0.5 + 2 
zgrid2 = -((11 - (2*xgrid-1)**2 - (ygrid+3)**2)**0.5) + 2
ax.plot_wireframe(xgrid, ygrid, zgrid)
ax.plot_wireframe(xgrid, ygrid, zgrid2)`

Comment: Это должно помочь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819498/plotting-ellipsoid-with-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

для отрсовки симметричных поверхностей иногда применяется их склеивание.
В данном случае необходимо 2 раза создать массив zgrid: +zgrid  и - zgrid
Я прикрепляю код без смещения по вертикальной оси, но его можно добавить если пересчитать zgrid.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
x = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)
y = np.arange(-10, 10, 0.01)
xgrid, ygrid = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zgrid = (11 - (2*xgrid-1)**2 - (ygrid+3)**2)**0.5 #изменила здесь
ax.plot_wireframe(xgrid, ygrid, zgrid)
ax.plot_wireframe(xgrid, ygrid, -zgrid)##добавила тут
plt.show()
```